# Postgres PSQL JSON Query array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I am trying to query my database to get rows that only have 'attached' in 'State' field inside json, and nothing i try works..

will be glad for any ideas :D

```
mydb=# SELECT attachments FROM aws_ec2_ebs_volumes;

 [{"State": "attached", "Device": "/dev/sda1", "VolumeId": "vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "AttachTime": "XXXX-XX-XXXX:XX:XXX", "InstanceId": "i-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy", "DeleteOnTermination": false}]
 [{"State": "attached", "Device": "/dev/sda1", "VolumeId": "vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "AttachTime": "XXXX-XX-XXXX:XX:XXX", "InstanceId": "i-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy", "DeleteOnTermination": true}]
 []
 []
 [{"State": "attached", "Device": "/dev/sda1", "VolumeId": "vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "AttachTime": "XXXX-XX-XXXX:XX:XXX", "InstanceId": "i-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy", "DeleteOnTermination": true}]
 []
 []
...
...
```

Basicly i need to get in results only rows containing string 'attached' in 'State', i have tried to run this:
However it return nothing.
I think its becouse the data is in json array (in [])..

```
mydb=# SELECT attachments FROM aws_ec2_ebs_volumes WHERE 'State' = 'attached';

attachments 
-------------
(0 rows)
```

I also tried this, but it didnt work either,

```
mydb=# SELECT attachments FROM aws_ec2_ebs_volumes WHERE attachments -->> 'State' = 'attached';
```

...returned nothing...

Expected proper result would be:

```
[{"State": "attached", "Device": "/dev/sda1", "VolumeId": "vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "AttachTime": "XXXX-XX-XXXX:XX:XXX", "InstanceId": "i-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy", "DeleteOnTermination": false}]
 [{"State": "attached", "Device": "/dev/sda1", "VolumeId": "vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "AttachTime": "XXXX-XX-XXXX:XX:XXX", "InstanceId": "i-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy", "DeleteOnTermination": true}]
 [{"State": "attached", "Device": "/dev/sda1", "VolumeId": "vol-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "AttachTime": "XXXX-XX-XXXX:XX:XXX", "InstanceId": "i-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy", "DeleteOnTermination": true}]
```

thanx guys!!

Comment: why do you have an array if you have not multiple values?

Comment: its not me, the array is automaticly created by software we use, its called "Cloudquery", they basicaly scan your AWS and store all metadata in DB for you to use as you wish.

Comment: incorporate horses comment in your answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

omg.. i think i found the answer, its only dash was missing...

```
mydb=# SELECT attachments 
       FROM "aws_ec2_ebs_volumes" 
       WHERE attachments ->0->> 'State' = 'attached';
```

the important part is `->0->>`

Basically from what i understand, it goes like this:

`->`  - means to go into array

`0`  - select first object inside array

`->>` - get actual json data (`{<data>}`) from object in array for evaluation with "=" sign.

hope this helps someone..

Comment: Alternatively you could have used `attachments #>> '{0,State}'`